# point_cloud cmake problem: cannot specify link libraries for target

Tags: ros, kinect, library, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi my friends, I am using ros-fuerte on 12.04. I am trying to compile the example from http://correll.cs.colorado.edu/?p=2807 which runs on ros-groovy. I have created my own CMakeLists.txt in order to make, however i encountered the following problem after running "make":

```
> mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package point_cloud_test
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
WARN, found multiple boost versions '[(1, 46, 1, '/usr', '/usr/include', True, True), (1, 54, 0, '/usr/local', '/usr/local/include', True, True)]', using latestWARN, found multiple boost versions '[(1, 46, 1, '/usr', '/usr/include', True, True), (1, 54, 0, '/usr/local', '/usr/local/include', True, True)]', using latestCMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:897 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "point_cloud_test" which is not
  built by this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:28 (rosbuild_link_boost)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The CMakeLists.txt is :

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
rosbuild_link_boost(point_cloud_test thread)
rosbuild_add_executable(point_cloud_test src/point_cloud_test.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(point_cloud_test libboost.lib)

find_package(VTK)

include ("${VTK_USE_FILE}")
```

I think the problem will be editing target_link_libraries, but i do not know which library to add and how to add it. Could someone help to give some instructions?
Thanks a lot in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73450/point_cloud-cmake-problem:-cannot-specify-link-libraries-for-target/) by [ljk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5470/ljk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2013-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved by:
rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
rosbuild_add_library(point_cloud_test src/point_cloud_test.cpp)
rosbuild_link_boost(point_cloud_test thread system)
rosbuild_add_executable(point_cloud_test src/point_cloud_test.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [ljk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5470/ljk/) with karma: 155 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0